# Laravel Sanctum middleware with OR condition

Tags: laravel

I am using `Laravel Sanctum` for Token Based Authentication.

I have created a `customer` guard for customer. For Other users its default `users` table.

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'customer' => [
        'driver' => 'sanctum',
        'provider' => 'customers',
    ],
],


'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],
    'customers' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => Customer::class,
    ],

],
```

I was authenticating **all other users** using `middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']` now for the given particular route, I want `customer` guard can also access this Route. But there is no such Functionality provided by `Laravel` for `OR` condition.

```
Route::group(['as' => 'business', 'prefix' => 'business', 'middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']], function () {
    Route::get('/categories', [BusinessCategoryController::class, 'listBusinessCategories'])->name('business-category');
    Route::get('/categories/{parentId}', [BusinessCategoryController::class, 'listBusinessSubCategories'])->name('business-sub-category');
});
```

I just want `middleware' => ['auth:sanctum'] or ['auth:customer']`

Comment: You can pass the guards to the middleware array like that: `'middleware' => ['auth:sanctum', 'auth:customer']`

Comment: `'middleware' => ['auth:sanctum', 'auth:customer']` It will check for both should be true. I just want one of them true.